# how to compare array string with int value

Tags: java, sql

i need to stop a job and wait for it to stop(usally it might take 1 min) and then execute the sql query  following is the code to stop the job.. iF Check_job value is 0 than the job is stopped .. i f1 than job is still running.

```
ArrayList<String> clean_stop_batch_job = new ArrayList<String>(); 
String Query_clean_stop_batch_job = "{ call pkg_batch_jobs.clean_stop_batch_job('BATCH_FILE_LOADER_JOB')}";
clean_stop_batch_job = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery_Proc("QA",  Query_clean_stop_batch_job);
```

I am doing follwoing to check if the  job  is stopped

```
ArrayList<String> Check_job = new ArrayList<String>(); 
String JOB_status = "select count(1) from user_scheduler_running_jobs where job_name='BATCH_FILE_LOADER_JOB'";
Check_job = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery_List2("QA", JOB_status);


while (Check_job.equals(1))
{        
    JOB_status = "select count(1) from user_scheduler_running_jobs where job_name='BATCH_FILE_LOADER_JOB'";
    Check_job = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery_List2("QA", JOB_status);              
}
```

I am getting error here that

> Unlikely argument type for `equals()`: `int` seems to be unrelated to `ArrayList<String>`

```
while (Check_job.equals(1))
```

What is best way to check if the  job to stopped  and then continue with the execution of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string can't be equal to an int. You can parse the integer into a string and then compare them:

```
while (Check_job.contains(String.valueOf(1)))
```

Comment: Thanks .. when i try your way i am still getting same error

Comment: Oh, it's a list. You should probably use `contains`.

Comment: or can you please suggent any other method to do it